# How can I edit source lookup path using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm having trouble debugging using mockito due to the impossibility of finding the source when stepping in with the debugger.

It simply won't find the class that is right inside the project.

The scenario is this:
I have class A and class Atest is the one using mockito to test class A.
Once class Atest is tested, there's a line in class A that calls a method in another class B, but the debugger cannot find the source for class B which is right in the project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What ide are you using and show your project setting.

Answer (score 0):

As @SureshKoya alludes, most IDEs provide a way at attach the sources for a Java .class file.

Depending on whether B is yours or third-party, and which IDE you're using, this may be fairly easy to fix.

Please provide further problem details.

Comment: Hey, guys, thank you.

I'm using Spring Tool Suite and my project is a Maven 3 project.

Class B is mine, is right in the same package as class A.

I'm wondering if maybe this ExtenderByMockito class in the debugger is something else or is referring to the regular class B.

I do a simple classB clazzB = mock(classB.class) and pass it as a parameter for classA constructor and when stepping in the method, it simply won't find classB for debugging. 

Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Your elaboration helps. Please put these details and preferably a code snippet in your question. I believe I have a better answer to your question now related to your use of mocking.

Comment: I have this class WidgetScriptService which has a SessionService member which in turn has a method getNGContentsForUser.
SessionService has its test class which runs OK, for all test cases.
WidgetScriptService has its test class (mockito - junit) which fails when calls WidgetScriptService.getContents which in turn calls SessionService and the aforementioned method.

ClassConnect ccScriptValues = classConnectSessionService.getNGContentsForUser(container, keyCode, user, timeNow, userRole);
 
 Test class for WidgetScriptService fails because the above line returns a null object.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to format here.

The method I'm talking about won't return null under any circumstance.
Thanks

Comment: Try backticks to format in comment. But better would be to add these details to your question. :)

Comment: This is the method:
`ClassConnectScript ccscript = new ClassConnectScript(container);
  String sessionsListResponse;
  String studentsResponse = null;
  boolean isWidgetEnabled =  true; ...some other calculations...
  if (isWidgetEnabled) {
            if (userRole.equals(Role.LEARNING_COACH)) {
                ccscript.setLc_cc_students(studentsResponse);
            }
            ccscript.setCc_sessions(sessionsListResponse);sessionsListResponse);
        }
ccscript.setWidgetEnabled(isWidgetEnabled);

        return ccscript;
`

Comment: But the real pickle is that the debugger is not finding the class that is right in the project.

Comment: I suspect that in `Atest` you hand a mock `B` in to `A` as `A`'s `B` dependency. The unit test then invokes a method on `A`, which calls its mock `B`. Mocking class `B` creates a subclass of `B`, thus the debugger does not reach any code in the real `B`. The `null` returned is likely the default return value of a Mockito mock object... Could you please test out this theory of mine?